# Roc curve straight line interpretation

Tags: python, roc, curve-fitting, sensitivity-specificity

How can I fix the straight line? is that mean that 70% of my cases that tag as positive and actually negative have the same value?
[image]

Comment: this must be a home work. exactly the same question was asked a couple of days ago

Comment: All your other green lines are vertical or horizontal.  So my guess is that the top green slightly-sloping line simply means you do not have any data for the high but not-total false positive rates.  I would not worry about it for AUC purposes, but simply recognise that you cannot usefully get True Positive Rates above the figure at its left end

Comment: @Aksakal Do you mean https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562816/straight-line-in-roc-curve

Comment: Looking at comments there, I think it is the same user

Comment: @Henry maybe OP wants to interpret every ROC curve assigned even if they look the same