# Why does my ROC curve have a sharp edge?

Tags: r, predictive-models, random-forest, roc

I was working on a random forest model in R and I got a ROC curve that looks like this. This is very odd since there is no curvature. The data does have mostly qualitative features with only 2-3 quantitative features. The data is also mostly one class (i.e. 80% of my data is in one class and 20% in the second class). It seems to favor sensitivity over specificity. The other issue is that the performance says that it only has 3 data points. I have a lot of data so I am not sure why it says only 3 points. Could someone explain what is happening with this ROC curve and why there is no curvature?

This is my code for the ROC curve plot.

```
#Test
pred <- ROCR::prediction(as.numeric(predict(forest.out, newdata = 
x_test, type =  "response")), labels = as.numeric(y_test$Success))
perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "for")

#Plot
plot(perf, xlab = "1-specificity", ylab = "sensitivity", main = "ROC 
curve")
abline(0,1, col = "grey")
plot(perf, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Did you plot predicted probabilities or predicted classes?

Comment: Make sure your model is not predicting all data points to be the larger class.

Comment: The predictions were across both classes. @Sycorax I am not actually sure if it is probabilities and predicted classes. I'll add more code to my question.

Comment: Related or possibly duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562816/straight-line-in-roc-curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to plot the ROC curve by a different method. I have the code below. I am still not sure why the code I had previously would not work.

```
library(pROC)
rf.roc<-roc(y_test$Success, forest.out$test$votes[,2])
plot(rf.roc, 
 col="red", 
 lwd=3, 
 main="ROC Curve",)
auc(rf.roc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for random forest’s predict, you’ll see that `type="response"` gives class labels. If you change the `type`, you can get probabilities (or votes), which will likely give a more typical ROC shape (many stair steps instead of 2 lines).

Comment: It gives me an error if I use type ="prob" and when I use type="class", nothing changes. It seems like a good suggestion but it's not working for me.